# Environment variables not loading inside docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, devops

I have two services which are dockerized. The first service is the `api` service which depends on the `mongo` service. However, for some reason, the `api` service can't connect to the mongo service because the environment variables inside the container are not been passed around well. I have two variables in my .env namely
`JWT_SECRET=somesecret`
`DB_URL_LOCAL=mongodb://mongo:27017/apii`
I tried setting the environment variables in the `docker-compose` file, when I run `docker-compose config` I see the variables and their values displayed, but my application can't detect these variables. MongoDB keeps throwing `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed` error.

I also tried to set the environment variables in the main `Dockerfile` but it still didn't work. Please I need some assistance. Here is a copy of my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file.

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

FROM base AS build

COPY package*.json .babelrc ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./src ./src
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production


FROM base AS release

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
USER node
EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "./dist/server/server.js" ]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    image: api
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    expose:
      - 4000
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DB_URL_LOCAL=$DB_URL_LOCAL
      - JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - './data:/data/db'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
```

Thank you.

Comment: In docker-compose.yml, environment variables should be declared in api service not mongo service with something like this `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DATABASE}`

Answer (score 1):

In docker-compose.yml, environment variables should be declared in api service not mongo service with something like this `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DATABASE}`

Use this, env_file is an alternative, [read more](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-variables-in-docker-compose-265a604c2006):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    image: api
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    expose:
      - 4000
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    env_file:
      - ./secret.env
    environment:
      - DB_URL_LOCAL=${DB_URL_LOCAL}
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - './data:/data/db'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this way also, both methods worked.